# Cannot get reddit authentication token from /api/v1/access_token

Tags: node.js, reddit, reddit-access-token

I'm currently using the node.js reddit (https://www.npmjs.com/package/reddit) plugin which will automatically get and process the authentication token but for some reason, it's failing for me.

```
Error: Cannot obtain token for username -Arniox-. invalid_grant.
```

with the following code:

```
const opts = {
   username: process.env.REDDIT_USERNAME,
   password: process.env.REDDIT_PASSWORD,
   appId: process.env.REDDIT_APP_ID,
   appSecret: process.env.REDDIT_APP_SECRET
}

//Initialize Reddit client
var reddit = new RedditJS.Client(opts);
```

I tried hunting for the issue and ended up finding out that I cannot even login via the direct API url here: https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token

I think maybe it might have something to do with my unique username (-Arniox-)? That's basically the only answer I have to this problem and I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding the issue. The developer I account was using to log into for the bot was 2 Factor authenticated which breaks the API and won't allow you to log in.

I had to create another account for a developer without 2-factor authentication.

Comment: Nowadays, you can simply turn the 2-factor authentication off if anything. Helpful answer!